# Why does my x86 assembly code cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

Again this is a homework. But trust me I've tried my best to solve this and Now I'm out of options.

Basically I'm given the task to convert this function from C into assembly.  It's part of a much bigger problem. I'm not gonna post the whole project because I don't want to impose my project onto you all. Basically just this one part. For those curious, the project is to take a BMP file and rotate 90 degrees clockwise.

Here is the C function:

```
void rotate_clock_helper (char* map, char *newmap, int mapsize, int width, int height) {
  int i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < width; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < height; j++){
      newmap[3*(((height)*(width-1-j))+(height-1-i))+0] = map[3*(width*(height-1-i)+j)+0];
      newmap[3*(((height)*(width-1-j))+(height-1-i))+1] = map[3*(width*(height-1-i)+j)+1];
      newmap[3*(((height)*(width-1-j))+(height-1-i))+2] = map[3*(width*(height-1-i)+j)+2];
    }
  }
}
```

And here's my attempt to redo it in assembly. Note, I don't care much about efficiency. I just need to finish something first.

```
extern printf

segment .data

segment .text

    global  rotate_clock_helper

rotate_clock_helper:        
    enter   4,0

    mov ecx,    0   ;i
    mov edx,    0   ;j

iloop:
    mov eax,    [ebp+20] ;width
    cmp eax,    ecx  ;while i < width keep looping
    je  done

jloop:
    mov eax,    [ebp-24] ;height
    cmp eax,    edx  ;while j < height keep looping
    je  resetJ

    ;; do operation here
    mov esi,    [ebp+08] ;map
    mov edi,    [ebp+12] ;newmap

    mov eax,    [ebp+20] ;width
    mov ebx,    [ebp+24] ;height

    sub eax,    1   ;width-1
    sub eax,    edx ;width-1-j
    imul    eax,    ebx ;(width-1-j)*height
    sub ebx,    1   ;height-1
    sub ebx,    ecx ;height-1-i
    add eax,    ebx ;(width-1-j)*height + (height-1-i)
    imul    eax,    3   ;3*eax
    mov [ebp-04], eax   ;saves this value to memory

    mov eax,    [ebp+20] ;width
    mov ebx,    [ebp+24] ;height

    sub ebx,    1   ;height - 1
    sub ebx,    ecx ;height-1-i
    imul    ebx,    eax ;width * (height-1-i)
    add ebx,    edx ;width * (height-1-i)+j
    imul    ebx,    3   ;ebx = 3 * ebx

    mov eax,    [ebp-04] ;self explanatory?
    ;; Now eax and ebx have the shift values
    add edi,    eax ;shift the edi value
    add esi,    ebx ;shift the esi value

    mov eax,    [esi]   ;move the value to eax
    mov [edi],  eax ;move the proper value into the newmap

    inc esi     ;esi + 1
    inc edi     ;edi + 1

    mov eax,    [esi]   ;same thing as before
    mov [edi],  eax ;same thing as before

    inc esi     ;esi + 1;
    inc edi     ;edi + 1

    mov eax,    [esi]   ;repeat again
    mov [edi], eax  ;repeat

    ;; operations end
    inc edx     ;j++

    jmp jloop

resetJ:
    mov edx,    0   ;reset j <- 0
    inc ecx     ;i++
    jmp iloop       

done:
    leave
ret
```

Can anyone help me figure out why this segmentation fault is happening?

Comment: You're most likely out of boundary for your array. How is it defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that this line:

```
jloop:
    mov eax,    [ebp-24] ;height
```

should be:

```
jloop:
    mov eax,    [ebp+24] ;height
```

As it is, your upper bound for the `jloop` is using some random value from elsewhere on the stack, not `height`

Comment: You my friend are my savior. and yes you're right. Its supposed to be ebp+24

Comment: I guess 8 hrs of work can make you miss tiny little details like that. Thanks again. You saved my hide :)

Comment: @user1029072 - we've *all* been there, at times.

Comment: @user1029072 - some of us have been there so regularly we get airmiles ;-)